# Isset in php - how it works

Tags: php, if-statement, isset

I´m learning PHP with book. And I found this:

```
 <?php 
         if(!isset($_GET['do']) || $_GET['do'] != 1) {
         switch ($_GET['type']) {
           case 'movie':
           echo 'are you sure?</br>';
           }
           echo '<a href="' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '&do=1">yes</a>';
           echo 'or <a href="admin.php">no</a>';
         } else {
    ?>
```

What is `if(!isset($_GET['do']) || $_GET['do'] != 1)` doing and why is it on the first line in script? Thanks!

Comment: Remove it and load your page again without a query string.

Comment: If `$_GET['do'])` doesn't exist, or if it exists but has any value other than `1` execute the switch block of code

Comment: And have your `error_reporting on`

Comment: I think `1` and not `-1` @MarkBaker

Comment: @Uchiha - yes, I misread... corrected

Comment: but why is it looking for `do` if `do` so far yet does not exist ? :)

Comment: if there is a get['do'] or it is not 1
read type.
If type is x echo y
...
...
else 
// do nothing

Comment: isset()    checks if a variable is declared and if it is, checks if it is not null to return true. Otherwise it returns false. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: @Rizier123 if I remove it. It is working (no error) only..evry time i clic yes url will change
`type=movie&id=15&do=1&do=1&do=1&do=1&do=1&do=1&do=1&do=1&do=1&do=1&do=1`

Answer (score 0):

If `$_GET['do'] = 1` **isset** would return **true**.

If `$_GET['do'] = NULL` **isset** would return **true**.

If `$_GET['do']` is not defined/declared then **isset** would return **false**.

This provides more information: https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/